# $x^a$ not defined in $\Re$ when $x$ negative?

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers

I know that by definition $x^a = \exp(a\log x)$ which is not defined when $x$ not in $\Re^∗_+$

Does it mean that for example $(-1)^3$ not defined for real numbers?

Comment: There are two things that should be observed. First of all, $-1^3$ is to be interpreted as $-(1^3)=-1,$ so I suspect you mean to ask whether $(-1)^3$ is real. Second, since $(-1)^3:=-1\cdot-1\cdot-1,$ then yes, it is. The answer below explains the situation well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $(-1)^3= (-1)(-1)(-1)= -1$ is perfectly well defined.  Your formula, $x^a= e^{a log(x)}$, is only correct when that logarithm exists.

Answer (score 3):

$(-1)^a$ is only real if $a$ is a rational number with an odd denominator.
$$(-1)^a = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
      1 & a=0 \\
      -1& a\in\{ \frac{p}{2q+1},p\in Z_+ , q\in Z  \} \\
      undefined & otherwise\\
\end{array} 
\right.$$

which is a pretty bizarre discontinuous function

so $(-1)^3 = -1$

but $\lim_{x \to3}(-1)^x$ does not exist.